# Stellar and contact form

Tags: jquery, forms, parallax, contacts

i have problem with stellar and all contact forms for joomla what i found on the same page on this website:

http://korab-coffee.cz/

Contact form doesn't do anything.
Somebody have solution?

Thank you very much.

Comment: What are you trying to do, and what exactly is the error you're getting or the problem you're having? Is this your website, or is it a site whose functionality you're using as an example of what you want to do on another site?

Comment: I want to sending emails from that contact form. That is my site. Try use that contact form and you will see the problem. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be using some dodgy javascript.

- When the page loads, it throws an error because you are trying to call windows.addevent, but have removed the mootools library which this requires
- Your JQuery is inserted in the footer of the page
- When you submit the form, it throws an error that the offset is null on line 48 of your js.js file
- If you turn off javascript, you can submit the form (whether or not it sends out emails server-side is another issue!)

Validating your code would be a good first step.

Comment: I've fix all this errors, there is still the same problem. If remove js.js it works. There is some conflict with this line: $(window).stellar(); I think.

Comment: it is possible to have a jquery conflict with php script?